# Necessario clicar 2 vezes no botão para adicionar input dinamicamente com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#add_row").click(function() {
        if(i <= 5)
        {
            $('#addr' + i).html("<div><input type='text' name='cirurgia' value="+i+"></div>");
            $('#input').append('<div id="addr' + (i + 1) + '">');
            i++;
        }   
    });

    $("#delete_row").click(function() 
    {
        if (i > 1) 
        {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

Quando o usuario clicar na `<div id="add_row">`, o script adiciona um input e se o usuario clicar na `<div id="delete_row">`, exclui o ultimo input adicionado.

Até aqui o script está funcionando corretamente, porém acontece que pra adicionar o 1° `input` o usuario precisa clicar 2 vezes no botão "add_row". Ai depois pra adicionar o 2°, 3°, 4° e 5° `inputs` é só clicar 1 vez mesmo, normalmente. Porque acontece isso?

HTML simples:

```
<input type="button" id="delete_row" value="deletar">
<input type="button" id="add_row" value="adicionar">
<br>
<div id="input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
$('#addr' + i).html("<div><input type='text' name='cirurgia' value="+i+"></div>");
```

Que tenta inicialmente ir ao elemento `#addr0` definir o `html`, quando esse ainda não existe, pois os elementos apenas são adicionados na linha seguinte.

Para resolver isto pode inverter a ordem das instruções e ajustar para `i+1` para que o primeiro elemento visível seja o `1`:

```
$('#input').append('<div id="addr' + (i+1) + '">');
$('#addr' + (i+1)).html("<div><input type='text' name='cirurgia' value="+(i+1)+"></div>");
```

Mais simples ainda é adicionar logo o html que pretende no `append`, sem ter que fazer depois passos:

```
i++;
$('#input').append(`
      <div id="addr${i}" class="addr">
          <div><input type='text' name='cirurgia' value="${i}"/></div>
      </div>`);
```

Aqui utilizei [*template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para facilitar a interpolação do `i` no meio do texto, assim como poder separar em várias linhas, indentando o html gerado.

Repare que adicionei também uma classe `addr` ao `<div>` principal para ajudar na remoção, que deve passar a ser:

```
$(".addr").last().remove();
i--;
```

Exemplo a funcionar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
      if(i <= 5)
      {
          i++;
          $('#input').append(`
          <div id="addr${i}" class="addr">
              <div><input type='text' name='cirurgia' value="${i}"/></div>
          </div>`);
      }   
  });

  $("#delete_row").click(function() 
  {
      if (i >= 1) 
      {
          $(".addr").last().remove();
          i--;
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input"></div>

<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
<button id="delete_row">Delete Row</button>
```

Comment: Excelente resposta Isac! Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado mesmo. Você é fera!